# Counting nth occurrence of a value

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif

Hoping I can be clear about this. I'm designing a digital lost & found system for a school I work for. Parents will fill out a google form which feeds to a spreadsheet, and I want to be able to track 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. requests for any given item (numbered 1-58).

Essentially, I want the sheet to look like:

| Name | Grade | Item | Request No. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sally | 1st | 51 | 1 |
| Joey | 2nd | 3 | 1 |
| Suzy | 2nd | 51 | 2 |
| Sally | 1st | 27 | 1 |
| Amahl | 3rd | 51 | 3 |

And so on...I imagine this can be done using `vlookup`, but I'm drawing a blank as to how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(C2:C="";;COUNTIFS(C2:C; C2:C; ROW(C2:C); "<="&ROW(C2:C))))
```

[image]

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try a dynamically expanding range:

```
=countifs($C$2:C2, C2)
```

Where the values you're counting are in C:C and you make the first bound of the range static ($C$2) and the second dynamic (C2).  Then when you fill down, the range will grow.

See this demo:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-AsjQ3sqTIpDOpEMSGLsullLY9P-0bEpuzkFAiQXwV0/edit#gid=0

I have assumed that the only criterion is the issue number and the grade, student, etc, don't matter.

Let me know if that works.